# UIDropInteractionDelegate performDrop not called?

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, uikit

I am trying to build a simple test app to learn Drag and Drop APIs. For this question I am focusing only on the Drop scenario. I have a blank View Controller, with the safari app open (multitasking) I then try to drag an image from google onto the View Controller's view.

I can drag the image from safari to my app's View Controller, but when I let go, this call below is never called:

```
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, performDrop session: UIDropSession)
```

This is my code:

```
class EditTestVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        view.addInteraction(UIDropInteraction(delegate: self))
    }

}

extension EditTestVC:UIDropInteractionDelegate {

    func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool { // 1
        print("canHandle session: \(session)")
        return true
//        return session.canLoadObjects(ofClass: UIImage.self)
    }

    func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, sessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession) -> UIDropProposal { // 2
        print("sessionDidUpdate session: \(session)")
        return UIDropProposal(operation: .copy)
    }

    func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, performDrop session: UIDropSession) {
        print("performDrop session: \(session)")
    }


}
```

The top two methods are called, this one:

```
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool
```

and this one:

```
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, sessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession) -> UIDropProposal
```

So, I am trying to figure out why this one:

```
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, performDrop session: UIDropSession)
```

is never called.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried waiting after a delay? Sometimes it takes time to load objects. Also the user has to confirm their intent to drop the item, so probably hold the object on the view controller view for a while.

Comment: I just tested your code and all methods are getting called. It must be a glitch. **Troubleshooting steps:** Delete app -> Restart the simulator -> Clean build folder -> Rebuild -> Run. You can also try running in different simulator first to save time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested your code and all methods are getting called. It must be a glitch.

**Troubleshooting steps:**

Delete app -> Restart the simulator -> Clean build folder -> Rebuild -> Run. You can also try running in different simulator first to save time.

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was a programming error where I've written the following:

```
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, sessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession) -> UIDropProposal {

    return UIDropProposal(operation: .move)
}
```

**But you cannot always use `move`! Only if `session.allowsMoveOperation` is `true`!**

From the [move documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidropoperation/move):

> You may use this operation only if the drop session's allowsMoveOperation property is true; otherwise, it's treated as a UIDropOperation.cancel operation. [...]

From the [cancel documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidropoperation/cancel):

> If the user attempts a drop activity, the drag operation is canceled and **the dropInteraction(_:performDrop:) delegate method is not called**.

Answer (score 2):

first of all, as of iOS 15 `dragSessionAllowsMoveOperation` is true by default

> Discussion
> If you don't implement this method, the default return
> value is YES.

In my case
`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator)`

was not called because I had set a breakpoint inside

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?)`

This breakpoint was preventing, for same reason, the other delegate method to be triggered. As soon as I removed them everything worked fine.

I hope this help others as it was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue and what i found was i did not set dropdelegate to self in collectionView.

```
collectionView.dropDelegate = self
```

After adding above line in viewDidLoad it worked!!

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.dragDelegate = self 
    collectionView.dropDelegate = self
    collectionView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
    collectionView.reorderingCadence = .fast

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```