# UITableViewDropDelegate PerformDrop not called when DropPoposal is Move (Xamarin)

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.forms, drag-and-drop

I'm writing a custom render for Xamarins UITableView that allows drag and drop.
I implemented the UITableViewDragDelegate and DropDelegate.

When I use UIDropOperation.Copy in the DropSessionDidUpdate function all is working fine as PerformDrop is called afterwards. The problem is Copy adds this nasty + icon to the cell while dragging which I don't want to have.
If I return UIDropOperation.Move then the + icon is gone. However PerformDrop is not called then anymore.

I found several hints to what could be wrong, for example do a clean:
[UIDropInteractionDelegate performDrop not called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54817243/uidropinteractiondelegate-performdrop-not-called)
In the same post one answer explains that Move can only be used if session.allowsMove is true.
So I implemented the CanMoveRow in my DataSource:

```
public override bool CanMoveRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
      return true;
}
```

but that didn't fix the issue. At least I can confirm that session.allowsMove is always true now.
In another thread (where I lost the link) for MacOS it was said that perform drop doesn't work if NSItemProvider of the UIDragItem doesn't have an object associated to. So I Implemented a wrapper for my Forms object and assigned it to the NSItemProvider:

```
        public override UIDragItem[] GetItemsForBeginningDragSession(UITableView tableView, IUIDragSession session, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            if (list.ItemsSource is IList source) //List is the instance of the Xamarin Forms ListView
            { //Check is always fulfilled
                var item = NSObjectWrapper.Wrap(source[indexPath.Row]);
                var itemProvider = new NSItemProvider(item, item.GetType().ToString());
                var dragItem = new UIDragItem(itemProvider);
                dragItem.LocalObject = item;
                return new UIDragItem[] { dragItem };
            }
            return null;
        }
```

but, still no change.

What am I doing wrong, how can I get move to perform a drop or how can I get rid of the + icon in the copy view?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you post your sample to github and share the link so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: Unfortunately not as it is corporate property :/

Comment: The UIDropOperation.move operation will not trigger the performDrop action. Check the tutorials:https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidropoperation/copy https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidropoperation/move

Comment: Hmm okay, generally copy is fine but is there any chance to remove the plus icon from the copy preview?

Comment: It is up to system design . If you do want to remove , you need to create a custom preview viewer .